# Magento 1.9.0.1: Change Shop by to Browse by

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to change "shop by" to "browse by" in the Left Nav panel under categories.  I am using Magento 1.9.0.1.

Comment: Looks like you've spent a whole lot of time trying your best to find an answer on your own ;)

Comment: Yes!  I am earning Magento the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

add this text to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

```
"Shop By","Browse By"
```